# Not editing the last line

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty new to VBA and i'm trying to write a little macro to edit text files to make them work in the different programmes we're working with over here. I got it almost all sorted out, but one thing keeps bothering me.

I wrote the macro to sift through a text file for certain lines and edit/remove text from those lines and write them to a new file.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("tempRO.txt")

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If Not InStr(strLine, "COVXX ") = 0 Then
    FileContentE = Left(FileContentE, InStr(FileContentE, "COVXX") - 1) & vbCrLf & strLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
```

I want the macro to remove all the text after "COVXX". It edits and writes all the lines to FileContentE without problem, except for the last line. Somehow it doesn't edit the last line. The output is like this:

```
data,data,data
data,data,data
data,data,data
data,data,data, COVXX 123124123521346247
(eof)
```

Does anyone have a clue what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for all your answers!

Oscar

Comment: can you copy paste the content of the loop between `Loop` and `objFile.Close` to see if its because it just doesnt run in the last run?

Comment: There’s nothing inbetween those two, the code you see in my post is copied right from the macro, no edits. It’s only part of the macro, with code in front of it and behind it, but not related to this file. I could post the enitre code tomorrow, if you’d like that

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

---

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("tempRO.txt")

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    FileContentE = FileContentE & Left$(strLine, InStr(strLine, "COVXX") - 3) & vbCrLf
Loop

objFile.Close
```

---

.

But it would be faster processing the entire file in memory

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestCOVXX()
    Debug.Print RemoveCOVXX("tempRO.txt")
End Sub

Public Function RemoveCOVXX(ByVal fName As String) As String
    Const FIND_TEXT = "COVXX"
    Dim fileNum As String, fileTxt As String, x As Variant, i As Long

    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open fName For Input As fileNum             'Open file
    fileTxt = Input(LOF(fileNum), fileNum)      'Get file content in fileTxt
    Close fileNum

    x = Split(fileTxt, vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        x(i) = Left$(x(i), InStr(x(i), FIND_TEXT) - 3)
    Next
    RemoveCOVXX = Join(x, vbCrLf)
End Function
```

---

My test file:

```
data,data,data, COVXX 123124123521346247
data,data,data, COVXX 123124123521346247
data,data,data, COVXX 123124123521346247
data,data,data, COVXX 123124123521346247
```

Result

```
data,data,data
data,data,data
data,data,data
data,data,data
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated the code like you said and it works now, with a little tweaking tot the rest of the code. I'll have a look at the second part of your answer, it requires me to rewrite most of the code.

Comment: The second part can be left as a Sub, you just need to add a parameter so you can pass the file name maybe), or you can change it to a Function and return the end result string `Join(x, vbCrLf)` instead of writing it to a file. (I'll change it to a Function)